# Laravel/Artisan Migrate & Seed Error [BadMethodCallException]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm running Laravel 4 in a local environment, and for some reason I cannot run `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan db:seed` without encountering the following error:

```
[BadMethodCallException]                                          
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::up()
```

I'm still relatively new to the framework, but I have tried all of the following to no avail:

- composer self-update & full re-install of vendor folder
- dump-autoload
- manually verified all autoloaded classes are mapped correctly and no incorrect dependencies exist
- re-installed migrations table

I used `php artisan migrate:make products --table=m_products --create` to generate the boilerplate, but in case you would like to see:

**Migration:** http://pastebin.com/931rivia (two custom migrations, pasted together for convenience)
**Seeds:** http://pastebin.com/zZMgi8K9 (both essentially the same, so only pasted one)

Edit: Just a note, I have made sure that there is no other class anywhere (in the namespace or otherwise) named "Users," "Products," or "Categories."  Models & controllers all have different naming conventions so I'm pretty sure no references are being overwritten...

Does anyone have any clue what might be going on?  Thank you!

Comment: It seems a very strange error, up() method isn't defined in Builder class. I've heard that running `php artisan clear-compiled` could helps. Could you give it a try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone else who may be having this issue, I did manage to find a resolution:

1) CLI logs are located in `/app/storage/logs/*` so chances are the stack trace there will help you identify any issues

2) The `Migrator` class ends up resolving the files in `/app/database/migrations` based on their NAME and NOT by using the ReflectionClass or otherwise to analyze the actual include.

**Note: This is where the error crept in--all the definitions were correct, but the file was accidentally renamed to: `SOME_DATE_category.php` INSTEAD OF `SOME_DATE_categories.php`, and thus the Migrator was trying to call `runUp()` on `Category` which is in fact a model.**

If anyone else comes across this in the future, look at the names of the files in your migrations folder and make sure they don't contain any strings which reference other classes.  (or else just make sure not to modify them from the initial artisan `migrate:create` command.)